# Moodle 1.9 backup format?

Tags: moodle

Where I can found Moodle 1.9 backup file specifiacation. Like http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Backup_2.0_for_developers for 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not been documented (see discussion [here](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=121595)). However, you may find the [developer docs for converting backups from 1.9 to 2.0](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Backup_1.9_conversion_for_developers) useful as it discusses the structure of a backup file in some depth.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like such a document exists. Your best bet would be to go through the [source code](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_19_STABLE/backup) for 1.9 and start from there.